# neo4j apoc.trigger.add with property update

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to implement trigger on neo4j to execute when single property gets changed

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('setUpdated-reference','
UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties}, "reference") AS prop 
WITH prop.node AS n, timestamp() as ts 
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, "updated", ts) YIELD node 
CALL apoc.log.info("setUpdated node %s", node) 
RETURN null 
', {phase:'after'});
```

however when I execute

```
MATCH (n:Currency) WHERE n.Name = "USD" SET n.reference = 1;
```

query execution gets stacked with no activity in logs 
therefore I can not determine the cause for such behavior

any advice is welcome

NOTE: I have also tried approach with SET

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('setUpdated2-reference','
UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties}, "reference") AS prop 
WITH prop.node AS n, timestamp() as ts 
SET n.updated = ts
WITH n AS node
CALL apoc.log.info("setUpdated node %s", node) 
RETURN null 
', {phase:'after'});
```

Comment: Just got this working when changed selector from
     { phase: "after" }
to 
    { phase: "before"}
it would be great if someone could explain....

Answer (score 2):

Found [this nice code](https://doc.linkurio.us/admin-manual/2.10.15/incremental-indexing/) in the documentation of Linkurious a visualization app that works on top of Neo4j.

For the neo4j 4.2.11 version that I'm using I had to tweak the triggers code a little bit to specify variables with $

Here:

```
// Add a timestamp on every node created:
CALL apoc.trigger.add('create-timestamp','UNWIND $createdNodes AS node
SET node.lastEditTimestamp = timestamp()', {phase:'before'});

// Add a timestamp on every node updated (property added/updated):
CALL apoc.trigger.add('update-insert-timestamp', 'UNWIND keys($assignedNodeProperties) as key
UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey($assignedNodeProperties, key) as update
WITH update.node as node
SET node.lastEditTimestamp = timestamp()', {phase:'before'});

//Add a timestamp on every node updated (property removed):
CALL apoc.trigger.add('update-remove-timestamp', 'UNWIND keys($removedNodeProperties) as key
UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey($removedNodeProperties, key) as update
WITH update.node as node
SET node.lastEditTimestamp = timestamp()', {phase:'before'});
```

After this is a good practice to create indexes on every node for your `lastEditTimestamp` property, ex: `CREATE INDEX ON :Address(lastEditTimestamp);`